# How to return a view from laravel controller function upon ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I am working on a bookstore project where books can be added to cart, a user can select many books for adding them to cart. when the user clicks on the `Add to Cart` button, I am adding the IDs of the selected books in a JS array called `cart`. When all the selected books are added to the cart then I want to link `<a>` tag with ajax call that will hit the url of a controller function and will send the JS `cart` array object to the controller function and then in the controller function, I want to return view to the browser, I do not want the controller function to return the response back to the ajax call but instead I want to return the view to the browser.

Here is the JS function that adds the ID of the selected books to the `cart` JS array:

```
function addToCart(id)
{
if(! cart.includes(id) ) cart.push(id);

cartLength.html(cart.length);
$('#successCart'+id).html('Book added to cart.');

}
```

Here is the `<a>` tag that calls the ajax function, the function name is showCart():

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); showCart();">
  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
  <span id="cartLength"></span>
</a>
```

Here is the `showCart()` function that has ajax code:

```
function showCart()
{


$.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });

$.ajax({
        url:"cart",
        method:'post',
        data:{cart:cart},
        dataType: 'html'
  })
 .done(function(msg){


  });
 .fail(function(msg){
    alert(msg.responseJSON.errors);
 });
}
```

Here is the controller function - I want this function to directly return the view to the browser without sending it back to the ajax call:

```
public function showCart(Request $request)
{
    return view('cart', ['cart' => $request->cart ]); // this should be returned to the browser and not to the ajax call
}
```

Here is the route for the controller function:

```
Route::post('/cart', 'HomeController@showCart')->name('home.cart');
```

**EDIT:**

I have temporarily solved the issue with the following tricks but that is not a permanent solution:

After calling the `showCart()` function from `ajax` for sending the `cart` array variable from `js` to `laravel` controller, I used the following logic to store the books in a session variable whose `ids` are stored in the `cart` array:

```
public function showCart(Request $request)
{

    session()->put('cart_books', Book::whereIn('id', $request->cart)->get()); 
    session()->save();
    return "success";

}
```

After storing the result of the query in a session variable, I created another `GET` route for `/cart` as below:

```
Route::get('/cart', 'HomeController@viewCart');
```

Then upon success of the `post` ajax call, I called `/cart` with `get` method as below:

```
.done(function(msg){
    console.log('calling cart');
    location.href = "cart"; // Here I call the `/cart` with `get` method which will hit the `viewCart()` function of HomeController which will return the view back to the browser along with the results that were stored in the session variable.

  })
```

And this is the `viewCart()` controller function that returns the view to the browser and sends the session variable's data to the view:

```
public function viewCart()
{
   $random_books = Book::all()->random(4);
   $categories = Category::all();
    return view('cart', ['cart_books' => session()->get('cart_books'), 
  'random_books' => $random_books, 'categories' => $categories]); 
}
```

I want the controller function to return the view to the browser without returning it to the ajax call, any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can return Raw html from ajax call by rendering and returning the view inside your controller as,

```php
return view('cart', ['cart' => $request->cart])->render();
```

This will return the raw HTML and you can further use it. However, returning HTML from ajax is not a good way, You can return JSON from the controller and render the view in frontend according to the JSON data.

Answer (score 2):

As the others said you can use

```
return view('cart', ['cart' => $request->cart])->render();
```

and in you jQuery do

```
.done(function(response){
    document.write(response);
});
```

Or you can return the link that its content should be shown to the user and redirect the user in your done method. So in your back-end you'll have

```
return route('cart', ['cart' => $request->cart]);
```

and in your front-end you'll have

```
.done(function(response){
    location.href = response;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller function just add render method like the following line

```
public function showCart(Request $request)
{
   return view('cart', ['cart' => $request->cart ])->render();
}
```

For js:

```
$.ajax({
method: 'POST', // Type of response and matches what we said in the route
url: '{{ route('home.cart') }}', // This is the url we gave in the route
data: {'cart' : cart}, // <-- this is your POST data
success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
    console.log(response);
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
}
});
```

Comment: It says `Internal Server Error`.

Comment: jquery.min.js:5 POST http://localhost:8080/wisdom2/public/cart 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:5
ajax @ jquery.min.js:5
showCart @ main.js:84
onclick @ (index):64

Comment: `The GET method is not supported for this route.`

Comment: It means you are calling it as get while it's not GET route,plz copy the route from routes files here

Comment: No, that is `post ` route, I have already added it to the question.

Comment: Oh, write the following for js:
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
Type not method

Comment: Now it cannot find the url, it goes to this url: http://localhost:8080/wisdom2/public/%7B%7B%20route('home.cart')%20%7D%7D

Comment: try the same code but replace {{ route('home.cart') }} with the right url to cart,
try to figure it out if you have any missing perfix.

Comment: I tried that as well but still get the `Internal Server Error`.

Comment: I do but cannot find the answer, I have temporarily solved the issue but that is not a permanent solution in my mind.

Comment: As we did not put our hands on the main problem, we will not be able to solve it permanently

Comment: Can you show log from laravel log file when that exception occured? Maybe we are missing something

Comment: I also wonder, if `url: '{{ route('home.cart') }}'` is correctly evaluated to url

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a XHR, so you shouldn't return the whole HTML *view* from your controller unless you plan to replace your existing element with the returned HTML, like how you're doing with `addToCart`. What you need here is a redirection after your POST, and your temporary solution isn't actually a bad solution :) Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180919/laravel-redirect-to-route-from-controller-when-called-by-ajax) as yours with the same answer. In fact, **I highly recommend your *temporary* solution** over the alternative solution below.

---

Since you wish to use the view returned from your controller without returning it to your ajax, a rather unorthodox approach would be to POST through a `<form>`. You can dynamically create a `<form>`, with the `<input>`s of your data, and submit.

```
function postData(actionUrl, method, data) {
    var mapForm = $('<form id="mapform" action="' + actionUrl + '" method="' + method.toLowerCase() + '"></form>');
    for (var key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            mapForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="' + key + '" id="' + key + '" value="' + data[key] + '" />');
        }
    }
    $('body').append(mapForm);
    mapForm.submit();
}

function showCart()
{
    postData('cart', 'post', cart);
}
```

*I borrowed the above code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660547/3209381). You can do the [same with vanilla JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133997/3209381) too.*